# CouchDB river for ElasticSearch: filter and receive full document?

Tags: couchdb, elasticsearch, couchapp

I'm trying to use a CouchDB design filter with my ElasticSearch CouchDB river.

It seems when we set a filter, the url used by ElasticSearch is:

> http://couchdb.com/_changes?feed=continuous&include_docs=true&heartbeat=10000&filter=stample/users

The matter is when i try to find my documents on ElasticSearch, i can't find anything.
After going to the CouchDB change stream url, i noticed that the full document is not sent to ElasticSearch.

When i remove the filter:

> http://couchdb.com/_changes?feed=continuous&include_docs=true&heartbeat=10000

Then the whole document is sent and i can find it in ElasticSearch.

So is it possible to use a CouchDB design filter and in the same time receive the whole document so that ElasticSearch can index it? Is it a CouchDB or ElasticSearch bug?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually my CouchDB filter was a deprecated one which only returned me deleted documents.